# How can I plot this function to see what it looks like?

Tags: plot, collatz

I have derived the below equations that describes the Collatz Tree.

```
C(x,0) = 3x+1 | For n = 0,
c(x,n) = x*2^n  | For n > 0 , For x > 0

Where:
x is an odd number, from x = 1 to Infinity, and
n is the number of steps in that branch, from n = 0 to infinity
```

I would like to see what it looks like when plotted but don't know how.

If there is some free open source program to do this, that would be good.

I'm not a programmer so might have trouble writing any code myself.

If someone knows how do this could they let me know how or even post up the plot if possible.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256765/discussion-on-question-by-mkda-how-can-i-plot-this-function-to-see-what-it-looks); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a 2-Dimensional plot of the functions translated into tree form.
There is no discontinuity in the function, it just looks that way since some higher number branches have not been plotted.
[Plot Of Collatz Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0fa1.jpg)